Does the magnetic susceptibility of paramagnetic materials decrease on increasing the magnetizing field?
When a paramagnetic material is placed in a magnetizing field (H), it gets magnetized due to the alignment of magnetic dipoles within it. For a certain temperature (kept fixed), is it possible that on increasing the value of the magnetizing field (H), the magnetic moments are all aligned and the magnetization (M) of the sample stagnates or saturates? That is, the magnetization (M) would remain the same even if the magnetizing field (H) is further increased. In that case, is it correct to believe that the magnetic susceptibility eventually starts decreasing?
